# How can I provide a bibliography file along with a package?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, packages, package-options, packages-testing

My general question is: **How can I provide a bibliography file along with a package?**

To be more precise: I want to write a package `specialBib.sty` that contains its own bib-file `specialBibFile.bib`. How can I make biber find the bib-file located inside the package directory?

`specialBib.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{specialBib}
\RequirePackage{biblatex}
% Execute some special biblatex things

\addbibresource{specialBibFile.bib}
```

`specialBibFile.bib`:

```
@misc{test-resource,
  author = {Test Author},
  title  = {Test Title},
  date   = {2023-11-19},
}
```

This package would sit in the tex-tree:

`/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/includeSpecialBib/specialBib.sty`

Along with the bib file:

`/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/includeSpecialBib/specialBibFile.bib`

Then the follwing should be working:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{specialBib}

\begin{document}
  Citing a resource from the special bibliography: \cite{test-resource}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

A MWE of the package with `filecontents` for convenience:

```
\ProvidesPackage{specialBib}
\RequirePackage{biblatex}
% Execute some special biblatex things

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{specialBibFile.bib}
  @misc{test-resource,
    author = {Test Author},
    title  = {Test Title},
    date   = {2023-11-19},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{specialBibFile.bib}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **bibatex**, the files are found by latex along `$TEXINPUTS` so you may simply distribute the `.bib` along with the package, they are on the same  search path so the `.bib` will be found if the package is, you do not need to do anything special.

While testing the package, you may simply put the package and the `.bib` file inside your local user tex-tree (e.g. `~/texmf/tex/latex/yourpackage`) and if necessary, update the filename database with `mktexlsr`.

**For bibtex**, the files are found on `$BIBINPUTS` so you can ask that texlive/miktex distribute the bib from

`texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/<yourpackage>/<yourbib.bib>.bib`

see for example the IEEE bib file at

`/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/ieeetran/IEEEabrv.bib`

Comment: Thank you! So I guess this would be the most elegant way to do it. Is this true also for biblatex bib-files?

Comment: yes (you can supply a package.tds.zip file to ctan with the packages in the runtime locations in addition to the flat source zip file normally submitted @Wamseln

Comment: @Wamseln er I think biblatex will use the tex input tree so you would want it with the package in that case

Comment: @Wamseln your question though is biblatex specific so I think I might delete this answer. The answer sjould be "just leave it  with the package" it will be found for the same reason the package is found, not because it's in the same directory but just because it's in the search path

Comment: @Wamseln updated answer

Comment: But when I put the `specialBib.sty` and `specialBibFile.bib` inside the appropriate places inside my texlive installation path (like described above: /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/includeSpecialBib/specialBibFile.bib), `kpsewhich specialBibFile.bib` returns no results and `biber` does not find it either.

Comment: never add files there by hand (or if you do as a test, run `mktexlsr` afterwards to rebuild the filename database, those directories should be managed by `tlmgr` add local files to (say) `~/texmf/tex/latex/yourpackage` @Wamseln

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle For anyone reading this: To test the package you can put the package + bib-file inside your local user tex-tree (e.g. `/home/user/texmf/tex/latex/specialBib/`) and update the filename database with `mktexlsr`, then kpsea and biber will be able to find it.

Comment: @Wamseln thanks for the edits, I added "if necessary" as usually the tree under your home directory is not restricted to mktexlsr and kpathsea will check the filesystem directly